# Direction of rotation in Feynman's Wobbling Plate

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, precession

For cube size 0.1,1,1, Mass=100; Initial angular velocity=ω(0)=[1;0.25;0.5]; we get

Moment of inertia tensor=I=[16.67,0,0;0,8.42,0;0,0,8.42]; Angular momentum magnitude=|L|=17.32;

If body axes=x’,y’,z’;

θ(t)=θ(0)=acos(I1ω1/|L|)=0.27; [rad; x’ with respect to L]

ϕ(t)=t*|L|/I3=2.05*t; [rad; x’ rotation about L]

Ψ(t)=t*ω1(I3-I1)/I3=-0.97*t; [rad; z’ rotation about x’]

1)What’s the meaning of the negative(-0.97), is it mean that z’ has left-handed rotation about x’?

2)x’ preccess about L every 3.06s; and z’ rotate about x’ every -6.41s;
But if we use the simulation in the link and draw z’, we see that after 6s z’ complete more than 1 circle about x’, why? It should do so only after 6.41s doesn’t it?

simulation link:
http://www.ialms.net/sim/3d-rigid-body-simulation/

[image]

Comment: The rotation matrix between body fixed coordinates system and internal system is dependent on those three angels, but it is still right handed created i.e you can create a negative angle by applying negative torque on the rigid body

Comment: In my example after 6.12s x' return to its initial position, but if we look now at z' we can see that it complete more than 1 circle (360+17 degree) how it's possible it suppose to complete 1 circle only after 6.41s?

Comment: how you got your equations $\phi(t),\theta(t),\psi(t)$ ?

Comment: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FeynmansWobblingPlate/

Comment: it's for disk, but if the disk and my cube have the same moment of inertia, they should rotate the same, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Theory behind this animation

**Euler Equation**:

$$I\vec{\dot{\omega}}+\vec{\omega}\times (I\,\vec{\omega})=0$$

with :

$$I=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} T_{{x}}&0&0\\ 0&T_{{y}}&0
\\ 0&0&T_{{y}}\end {array} \right]$$

$$\vec\omega=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \omega_{{x}}\\ \omega_{{y}
}\\ \omega_{{z}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

with the initial conditions
$~\omega_x(0)=\omega_{x0}~,~\omega_y(0)=\omega_{y0}~,~\omega_z(0)=\omega_{z0}~$
you can obtain the solution for $~\vec{\omega}(\tau)$

$$\omega_x(\tau)=\omega_{x0}$$
$$\omega_y(\tau)=-\omega_{{{ z0}}}\sin \left( {\frac {\omega_{{{ x0}}} \left( -T_
{{y}}+T_{{x}} \right) \tau}{T_{{y}}}} \right) +\omega_{{{ y0}}}\cos
 \left( {\frac {\omega_{{{ x0}}} \left( -T_{{y}}+T_{{x}} \right)
\tau}{T_{{y}}}} \right)
$$
$$\omega_z(\tau)=\omega_{{{ z0}}}\cos \left( {\frac {\omega_{{{ x0}}} \left( -T_{
{y}}+T_{{x}} \right) \tau}{T_{{y}}}} \right) +\omega_{{{ y0}}}\sin
 \left( {\frac {\omega_{{{ x0}}} \left( -T_{{y}}+T_{{x}} \right)
\tau}{T_{{y}}}} \right)
$$

**Rotation Matrix**

The rotation matrix between the body and inertial system is:

$$S= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&\cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) &-\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\ 0
&\sin \left( \varphi  \right) &\cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
\,\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\sin
 \left( \vartheta  \right) \\ 0&1&0
\\ -\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\cos \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right] 
\, \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \psi \right) &-\sin \left( 
\psi \right) &0\\ \sin \left( \psi \right) &\cos
 \left( \psi \right) &0\\ 0&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

from here you get the equation:

$$\left[ \begin {array}{c} \dot\varphi \\ \dot\vartheta 
\\ \dot\psi \end {array} \right] 
= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {\frac {\cos \left( \psi \right) }{\cos
 \left( \vartheta  \right) }}&-{\frac {\sin \left( \psi \right) }{\cos
 \left( \vartheta  \right) }}&0\\ \sin \left( \psi
 \right) &\cos \left( \psi \right) &0\\ -{\frac {
\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \cos \left( \psi \right) }{\cos \left( 
\vartheta  \right) }}&{\frac {\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \sin
 \left( \psi \right) }{\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) }}&1\end {array}
 \right] \,\left[ \begin {array}{c} \omega_{{x}}\\ \omega_{{y}
}\\ \omega_{{z}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

you don't have analytical solution for this ODE, you have to solve it numerical after that you obtain
$~\varphi(\tau)~,\vartheta(\tau)~,\psi(\tau)~$ so you can animate the rigid body with the rotation matrix $~S=S(\tau)$

Comment: in the detail of the walfram link ψ(t)=W3(0)*(I(1,1)-I(3,3))/I(1,1); so this is an analytical solution, but what does it mean? it supposes to be relative rotation, but I don't understand exactly of what and how can I calculate it in another way

Comment: ok, thank you, now I understand